# Windows 8, .NET 4.5 DefineUninitializedData issue

Tags: windows-8, .net-4.5, reflection.emit, il

I am trying to get to the bottom of an issue with our compiler and .NET 4.5 with Windows 8. I have simplified it down to a small piece of code and wondered if anyone has any insight into the issue. I have written some C# that uses reflection to generate an assembly that shows the problem. The C# is (in a VS2010 solution here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10931452/sdata.zip) is at the bottom of this post. It creates a class ‘sdata’ and adds a static field called ‘blank16’ to it. It then creates a static constructor that initialises this field. The resulting executable is written to c:\temp\sdatatest.exe. When sdatatest is run on Windows 8 under .NET 4.5 it produces:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'sdata' threw an exception. --->
>   System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. at
>   sdata..cctor()  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  at
>   sdata.main()

When run on Windows 7 with .NET 4.5 installed it runs. When run on earlier .NET frameworks it also runs – and has done for a decade.

The IL produced looks valid:

[image]

The JITed x86 code looks perfectly valid too:

[image]

The value of edi look suspiciously like a location in the loaded executable rather than in the managed memory space and if it is read only that would explain the access violation. Why would this change on Windows 8 though?

C# to produce the sdatatest assembly:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Threading;

namespace sdata
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName( );
            name.Name = "sdatatest.exe";
            string exepath = "c:\\temp\\" + name.Name;
            name.CodeBase = "file:://" + exepath;
            AssemblyBuilder ass_bldr = Thread.GetDomain( ).DefineDynamicAssembly( name, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave, Path.GetDirectoryName( exepath ));
            ModuleBuilder module_bldr = ass_bldr.DefineDynamicModule( Path.GetFileName( exepath ), Path.GetFileName( exepath ), true );
            TypeBuilder tb = module_bldr.DefineType( "sdata", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass );
            TypeBuilder sixteen = module_bldr.DefineType( "sixteen", TypeAttributes.Sealed, typeof( ValueType ), PackingSize.Size8, 16 ); // value type of size 16
            Type t16 = sixteen.CreateType( );
            var fb = tb.DefineUninitializedData( "blank16", 16, FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static );
            ConstructorBuilder cons = tb.DefineConstructor( MethodAttributes.Static, CallingConventions.Standard, Type.EmptyTypes ); // ..cctor
            var il = cons.GetILGenerator( );
            il.BeginScope( );
            il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldsflda, fb );
            il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0 );
            il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 16 );
            il.Emit( OpCodes.Initblk );
            il.Emit( OpCodes.Ret );
            il.EndScope( );
            MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod( "main", MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public );
            il = mb.GetILGenerator( );
            il.BeginScope( );
            il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldsflda, fb );
            il.Emit( OpCodes.Pop );
            il.Emit( OpCodes.Ret );
            il.EndScope( );
            tb.CreateType( );
            ass_bldr.SetEntryPoint( mb );
            ass_bldr.Save( Path.GetFileName( exepath ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you tried running PEVerify on the generated assembly?

Comment: ModuleBuilder.CreateGlobalFunctions() is missing from your code, it is required when you use DefineUninitializedData().  If that doesn't help then file a bug report at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: ModuleBuilder.CreateGlobalFunctions() didn't make any difference (unfortunately).

Comment: PEVerify is interesting. It complained about the assembly having a '.' in the name. So I fixed it, and now it shows:

[IL]: Error: [C:\temp\sdatatest.exe : sdata::.cctor][offset 0x00000000] Cannot modify an imaged based (RVA) static
[IL]: Error: [C:\temp\sdatatest.exe : sdata::main][offset 0x00000000] Cannot modify an imaged based (RVA) static

Which sort of suggests the issue but doesn't suggest why 

a) it has worked for 10 years
b) what would DefineUninitializedData be for if it only provided uninitialised read only data...

Comment: @Rob Could you email me at netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com? I want to help take a look. Regards, Varun Gupta (Microsoft .NET Framework Compatibility Team)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that Windows 8 has changed the access rights on the .sdata section: making it read-only. If you are using DefineUninitializedData then you code will probably break on Windows 8 and will need changing.